# How to align aside as sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page for employees biography with one picture. The biography (content) to display on the left and photo of the employee on the right as sidebar. The page also have footer with full width.

I used CSS to layout the page, and `float:left` both content and photos and set the width divided accordingly, but the photo (aside) does not display on the right and it appear under the content, however I used `display:inline` properties for both content and aside. I am trying to display the `aside` on the right side of the `article`.

```css
article, h1, aside, footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

article {
  width: 60%
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

aside {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Biography</h1>
    <p>General Information goes here</p>
    <p>Rest of information goes here</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h2>Employee Photo</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright goes here</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues should be corrected:

1. You have width set to 60% and 40% for `article` and `aside`, however they also have `padding:20px`, that make the total width over 100%, an easy fix would be set `box-sizing:border-box`, it makes the padding as part of the % width.
2. If you set `float:left` on an element, that turns it to a *replaced element*, `display:inline` or `block` won't take any effects.
3. There is an syntax error, it's missing `;` at the end of `width: 60%`.
4. It would better to also set `img {max-width:100%; height:auto;}`, to make it to be responsive.

Below is the updated example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, h1, aside, footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: gray;
}

article {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  clear: both;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Biography</h1>
    <p>General Information goes here</p>
    <p>Rest of information goes here</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h2>Employee Photo</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright goes here</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a flex container will do.

```
<div style="display:flex">
  <article>...</article>
  <aside>...</aside>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```